# Python Regex - Match multiple expression with groups

Tags: python, regex

I have a string:

```
property1=1234, property2=102.201.333, property3=abc
```

I want to capture 1234 and 102.201.333. I am trying to use the regex:

```
property1=([^,]*)|property2=([^,]*)
```

But it only manages to capture one of the values. Based on  [this link](http://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html)  I also  tried:

```
((?:property1=([^,]*)|property2=([^,])+)
(?:(property1=([^,]*)|property2=([^,])+)
```

They capture an extra group from somewhere I can't figure.

What am I missing?

P.S. I am using re.search().

Edit: There may be something wrong in my calling code:

```
m = re.search('property1=([^,]*)|property2=([^,]*)', text);
print m.groups()
```

Edit2:  It doesn't have to be propertyX. It can be anything:

```
foo1=123, bar=101.2.3, foobar=abc
```

even

```
foo1=123, bar=weirdbar[345], foobar=abc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expressions are great for things that act like [lexemes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexeme), not so good for general purpose parsing.

In this case, though, it looks like your "configuration-y string" *may* consist solely of a sequence of lexemes of the form: <kbd>word</kbd> `=` <kbd>value</kbd> [ `,` <kbd>word</kbd> `=` <kbd>value</kbd> ... ].  If so, you can use a regexp and repetition.  The right regexp depends on the exact form of <kbd>word</kbd> and <kbd>value</kbd>, though (and to a lesser extent, whether you want to check for errors).  For instance, is:

```
this="a string with spaces", that = 42, quote mark = "
```

allowed, or not?  If so, is `this` set to `a string with spaces` (no quotes) or `"a string with spaces"` (includes quotes)?  Is `that` set to  `42` (which has a leading blank) or just `42` (which does not)?  Is `quote mark` (which has embedded spaces) allowed, and is it set to one double-quote mark?  Do double quotes, if present, "escape" commas, so that you can write:

```
greeting="Hello, world."
```

Assuming spaces are forbidden, and the <kbd>word</kbd> and <kbd>value</kbd> parts are simply "alphanumerics as matched by `\w`":

```
for word, value in re.findall(r'([\w]+)=([\w]+)', string):
    print word, value
```

It's clear from the `102.201.333` value that `\w` is not sufficient for the `value` match, though.  If <kbd>value</kbd> is "everything not a comma" (which includes whitespace), then:

```
for word, value in re.findall(r'([\w]+)=([^,]+)', string):
    print word, value
```

gets closer.  These all ignore "junk" and disallow spaces around the `=` sign.  If `string` is `"$a=this, b = that, c=102.201.333,,"`, the second `for` loop prints:

```
a this
c 102.201.333
```

The dollar-sign (not an alphanumeric character) is ignored, the value for `b` is ignored due to white-space, and the two commas after the value for `c` are also ignored.

Comment: Well my usecase is both simpler and harder than this:
Its is simpler because:

* Property1, Property2 (i.e words) are known and hardcoded
* I can live with some amount of error

It is difficult because
* Value can be complex (weirdbar[345, weirderbar[123]])

Comment: I realized that I am trying to do more of Deseriazlization than of regex parsing. So I am shifting to another approach altogether. But I'll mark your solution as the answer for being the most complete.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, we could use some string splitting to create a dictionary.

```
text = "property1=1234, property2=102.201.333, property3=abc"
data = dict(p.split('=') for p in text.split(', '))
print data["property2"] # '102.201.333'
```

Comment: Interesting, might use this as a last resort.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a `|`. That means your regex will match either the thing on the left of the bar, or the thing on the right.

Answer (score 0):

you could try:

```
property_regex = re.compile('property[0-9]+=(?P<property_value>[^\s]+)')
```

that would match any property after the equals sign and before a space. It would be accessible from the name `property_value` just like the documentation says:

copied from [python re documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax)

> For example, if the pattern is (?P[a-zA-Z_]\w*), the group can be
>   referenced by its name in arguments to methods of match objects, such
>   as m.group('id') or m.end('id'), and also by name in the regular
>   expression itself (using (?P=id)) and replacement text given to .sub()
>   (using \g).

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
property_regex = re.compile('property[0-9]+=([^\s]+)')
```

Comment: Sorry, I oversimplified here. It doesn't have to be propertyX. It can be anything
    foo1=123, bar=101.2.3, foobar=abc

Answer (score 0):

I have tried building a regular expression for you which will give you the values after property1= and property2 but I am not sure how you use them in Python.

**Edit**

now captures other stuff apart from property before the '=' sign.

This is my original regular expression which does capture the value.

(?<=[\w]=).*?[^,]+

and this is a variation of the above, IMO what I believe you would need to use in Python

```
/(?<=[\w]=).*?[^,]+/g
```